# PHP Interoperability - Print statements not showing in command line

Tags: php, fortran, php-7, fortran95

I am having issues with PHP not returning print statements from Fortran. The idea is that PHP executes a command to compile a Fortran file then runs it.

You are asked to input a number via print statement, problem is there is none showing up to CMD but the program is working as intended - when I enter an "incorrect" number it waits for me to enter a "correct" number then completes execution.

How do I get the command line to print the statements nested in the Fortran file?

The PHP Script

```
$<?php
// This is a script to test interoperability between Fortran and PHP
$ExecutionStringOne = "gfortran C:\Users\****\Desktop\Programs\Fortran_Programs\FibSequence.f95 -o C:\Users\****\Desktop\Programs\Fortran_Programs\FibSequenceTest";
$ExecutionStringTwo = "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Programs\Fortran_Programs\FibSequenceTest.exe";
exec ($ExecutionStringOne);
exec ($ExecutionStringTwo);
?>
```

Fortran Code:

```
! This program will calculate the first 7 numbers in the Fibonacci sequence with user input as well as error checking
    Program FibSequence
        implicit none
        ! Defining our global variables 
        Integer :: acceptValue, n_terms          ! Accept Value: 0, 1 - This tracks whether input is correct (0 False, 1 True) , N_terms: Number of terms
        real    :: timeForSubRoutineStart, timeForSubRoutineEnd, totalTime ! Tracks execution time of subroutine
        write(*,*) "Please input an amount of terms to calculate sequentially to - This number can be between 1 and 7"
        read *, n_terms
        if (n_terms > 0 .AND. n_terms <= 7) then
            acceptValue = 1                      ! This is true therefore run program (This isnt really needed but for consistency)
            Call calculateSequence(n_terms)
        else
            acceptValue = 0                      ! This is false therefore run the read again and keep doing so until the output is correct
            do while ( acceptValue == 0 )
                write(*,*) "Invalid number please enter one within the given range - Range ( 1 - 7 )"
                read *, n_terms
                if (n_terms > 0 .AND. n_terms <= 7) then 
                    acceptValue = 1                     !Yay correct input
                    Call calculateSequence(n_terms)
                else
                    write(*,*) "Invalid number, try again" !Boo invalid input
                end if 
            end do
        end if
    End Program
    
    Subroutine calculateSequence(NumberOfTerms)
        Integer :: pt1 = 0, pt2 = 1
        Integer :: pt3
        Call CPU_TIME(timeForSubRoutineStart)
        i = NumberOfTerms
        
        do while (i > 0)
            pt3 = pt1
            pt1 = pt1 + pt2
            pt2 = pt3
            i = i-1
            write(*,*) "Point A Equals", pt1, "Point B Equals", pt2, "Calculated Next Number", pt3
            write(*,*) "Current Term = ", i
            write(*,*) "This program calculated this many points ", NumberOfTerms
            write(*,*) "End" 
        end do
        Call CPU_TIME(timeForSubRoutineEnd)
        totalTime = timeEnd - timeBegin
        write(*,*) "This program took ", totalTime, " seconds to execute"
    end Subroutine calculateSequence
```

[image]

*EDIT - Added a new image regarding the issue* @roygvib Suggested ECHO which is returning some print statements now

[image]

Comment: Possibly, is this line of the Fortran code (`Integer :: pt1 = 0, pt2 = 1`) intended to be the initialization of  `pt1` and `pt2`  upon every call of `calculateSequence()` (like in C or similar languages)?

Comment: And according to this page (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), we may need `echo` in front of `exec()` or add an output argument to `exec()`? (I have no experience with PHP so just guessing...)

Comment: @roygvib I will try using ```echo``` to see if that fixes the issue quite finicky lol.

To address the Integer question, the Subroutine is working as intended. I was debugging thinking of what was happening that couldn't be seen in the terminal window. When incorrect numbers are added *Anything under 0 and over 7* the program will go to a new line indicating that the program is trying to ```read*, n_terms``` once again and this can be verified by looking at the ```Main()``` of the program it will never execute the subroutine until a correct number is supplied and will subsequently exit.

Comment: @roygvib I read that page a couple times and that that maybe I needed to include a variable for returning the "data" but there is nothing to be returned - it's a series of print statements so I ran into a dead end there.

Comment: It's interesting that "System()" works fine here .. :) Btw, the reason why I asked about the line "Integer :: pt1 = 0, pt2 = 1" is that Fortran implicitly adds the SAVE attribute (which is similar to "static" in C-like languages). So, the above declaration is equivalent to "Integer, save :: pt1 = 0, pt2 = 1", and the value of pt1 and pt2 are retained among multiple calls (i.e. they are _not_ initialized to 0 and 1 after the second call!). This is a notorious feature of Fortran (IMO), and we have to be very careful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a users help @roygvib I was able to find a solution to the problem.

PHP several different ways for executing files and commands - One as was used in the problem set is `exec()` which will execute the program and not return any output.

On the other hand there exists `System()` which will launch the given commands and executable and return any output that exists within the lifetime of the program execution.

TLDR: Using `System` instead of `Exec` resolved the issues I was having.

```
system ($ExecutionStringOne);
system ($ExecutionStringTwo);
```

[image]